# Navigation Bar not showing when presenting View?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

In another file I'm creating an instance of my view controller from another storyboard and presenting it like so:

```
let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "UserProfile", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profileID") as! ProfileViewController
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In my storyboard I have the correct storyboard ID and embedded my view controller in a UINavigationController. I also set the initial view controller to the UINavigationController.

Why isn't it showing up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create object of view controller then add navigation controller to it, and then present it :

```
let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as! ViewController
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1) // Creating a navigation controller with VC1 at the root of the navigation stack.
self.presentViewController(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You can do same using objective-c as well.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you're presenting the view controller (Please note, it's not navigation controller).

What you can do:

1. Push the view controller

   ```
   let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "UserProfile", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profileID") as! ProfileViewController
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
   ```
2. Present the navigation controller

   ```
   let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "UserProfile", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profileID") as! ProfileViewController

   let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

   self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who still use Objective-C:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"Storyboard" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
ViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: vc];
[self presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Don't forget to thick the button:

[image]